# How to "fully" remove fuse support from OpenBSD?

Tags: security, openbsd, fuse

How can someone remove the fuse support from OpenBSD?

Would it require to recompile the kernel?

Or just a config modifications or remove some binaries? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel support for `FUSE`

```
# grep FUSE /sys/conf/GENERIC
option          FUSE            # FUSE
```

would need to be removed; assuming `sys.tar.gz` has been foisted onto the system and all the latest and greatest patches applied

```
# cd /sys/conf
# cp GENERIC NOFUSE
# (echo /FUSE; echo d; echo w; echo q) | ed NOFUSE
4048
option          FUSE            # FUSE
4027
# grep FUSE NOFUSE
# cd /sys/arch/`uname -m`/conf
# cp GENERIC NOFUSE
# grep GENERIC NOFUSE
#       $OpenBSD: GENERIC,v 1.445 2017/08/28 19:32:53 jasper Exp $
include         "../../../conf/GENERIC"
# ed NOFUSE
20842
/\/GENERIC
include         "../../../conf/GENERIC"
s/GENERIC/NOFUSE
include         "../../../conf/NOFUSE"
w
20841
q
# config NOFUSE
...
# cd ../compile/NOFUSE
# make
...
# make install
...
# reboot
```

Man pages such as `config(8)` and `release(8)` and `boot(8)` might be worth a peek, and that the above builds a `MP` or `SP` kernel as is appropriate for the system...

Comment: wow, thx, do you think of any method, how to test that fuse is really removed this way?

Comment: and what about "pseudo-device fuse fuse device"?